# Creating multiple instances of same part with DirectoryCatalog in .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mef

I'm trying to create multiple instances of same part imported using DirectoryCatalog, in order to let classes i already have use a "personal" instance of same part like so:

```
interface TMyType
{
    some method...
}

public class PluginHelper
{
    ImportMany of type TMyType with CreationPolicy non shared
    ...

    public bool GetPluginByName(string name)
    {
        GetPlugin based on name requested
    }
}

class A
{
    plugin = PluginHelper.GetPluginByName("PLUGIN1")
}

class B
{
    plugin = PluginHelper.GetPluginByName("PLUGIN1")
}
```

This actually works but A.plugin is same instance as B.plugin... Using .Net 4 (Not 4.5) looks like i should move the import in each class and then select the desired plugin there. I know I can use Lazy in order to avoid creation of parts at composition, but still looks kinda ugly...

Been googling quite a lot to no avail.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a factory for this?

```
//inside class: example PluginFactory
public IPlugin ReturnSomeType<T>() where T : IPlugin, new()
{
    return new T();
}

//if the plugins don't share the same interface
public T ReturnSomeType<T>() where T : class, new()
{
    return new T();
}

//usage
var factory = new PluginFactory();
var pluginA = factory.ReturnSomeType<SomePluginA>();
var pluginB = factory.ReturnSomeType<SomePluginB>();
```

Comment: I'm quite new to MEF and .NET 4 (been using .NET 2 for ages). The solution looks this one but I cannot understand how can i create the different plugins basing on the name (i do have a property in classes that states the plugin name).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution to my problem, and also what Stephen was trying to explain me :)

[Factory pattern with Managed Ext Framwork (MEF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292563/factory-pattern-with-managed-ext-framwork-mef)