# Factory pattern, Avoid same switch case for different interface

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface, factory-pattern

I have a Model which Implements 3 different interfaces

```
public class CustomerRateSettingModel :  IBaseFactory, IHandleSearch, IHandleSearchAggregate
```

I am very new with implementing design patterns and trying to implement Factory pattern to create instances.
But I am unable to find a proper way to avoid the identical Switch statements while writing Factory

```
  public static IHandleSearch GetClassInstanceForSearch(string className)
    {
        switch (className.ToLower())
        {
            case "customerratesettingmodel":
                return new CustomerRateSettingModel();

            default: return null;
        }
    }

    private static IBaseFactory ManufactureModel(string className)
    {
        switch (className.ToLower())
        {
            case "customerratesettingmodel":
                return new CustomerRateSettingModel();

            default: return null;
        }
    }
```

Is there is any right way to handle scenarios like that?

For Reference : 
the code calling the factory

```
  IHandleSearch instance = ModelFactory.GetClassInstanceForSearch(modelName);


 var modelResult = instance.GetSearch(indexName, searchHistory.SearchParameters);
```

Comment: This isn't a standard factory pattern. This looks like some kind of dependency injection? A factory pattern would just create objects not use strings to **find** objects

Comment: I think you should look into DI frameworks like Unity of Simple Injector

Comment: @Liam: U are correct, I should send the indicators instead of class names, but yes, I am creating a concrete object on runtime

Comment: @mjwills : But there has to be a return type right? On the other end, I am using the interface functions implemented by the concrete instance

Comment: I have had success using MEF for implementing factory
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292563/factory-pattern-with-managed-ext-framework-mef

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a `Dictionary<string,Func<object>>` to map names to object makers. Use `as` operator to test `object` for compliance with the desired interface:

```
static readonly IDictionary<string,Func<object>> Makers = new Dictionary<string,Func<object>> {
    ["customerratesettingmodel"] = () => new CustomerRateSettingModel()
};
public static IHandleSearch GetClassInstanceForSearch(string className) {
    return Construct<IHandleSearch>(className);
}
public static IBaseFactory GetClassInstanceForSearch(string className) {
    return Construct<IBaseFactory>(className);
}
private static T Construct<T>(string className) where T : class {
    if (!Makers.TryGetValue(className.ToLower(), out var makeObject) {
        return null;
    }
    return makeObject() as T;
}
```