# Instantiating a generic type from a dictionary

Tags: c#, interface

I have a few classes that implement the ITerminalCommand interface:

```
public class TerminalCommandHelp : MonoBehaviour, ITerminalCommand { //... }
public class TerminalCommandExit : MonoBehaviour, ITerminalCommand { //... }
```

In a separate class, I would like to be able to look up a string in a dictionary and create a new instance of the ITerminalCommand, but I don't know how I would go about doing this, so below I have written some sort of pseudo-code in the hopes that someone might understand what I am trying to do.

```
Dictionary<string, ITerminalCommand> validInputs = new Dictionary<string, ITerminalCommand>()
    {
        {
            "help", 
            //Some reference to the TerminalCommandHelp class so I can instantiate it at my own will
        },

        {   
            "exit",
            //Some reference to the TerminalCommandExit class so I can instantiate it at my own will
        }
    };

    //Create a new object based on the key I am looking up, and supply some arguments to the constructor
     ITerminalCommand genericTerminalCommand = new validInputs["help"](arguments);

    //Run a method on the newly instantiated object
    genericTerminalCommand.Execute();
```

**How can I 'abstractly' reference a class type in a dictionary so I can instantiate it and also supply some arguments to it?**

Comment: Why not just store instances of the classes in the dictionary?

Comment: I could, but then each time I want to use the class I have to remove the data that was previously inputted in it. I think I would prefer to create a new object each time... unless that is a dumb thing to do.

Comment: Didn't you ask the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63235332/c-using-a-dictionary-of-string-interface-to-reference-different-classes) already?

Comment: I did, and their solution was what Rufus mentioned above -- to get a reference to an already-instantiated object. What I want to do though is instantiate that 'type', rather than modify an existing one

Comment: Are you familiar with [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netcore-3.1)? It sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer if it doesn't work for what you want? Also, don't post duplicate questions

Comment: I'd just `Dictionary<string, Func<ITerminalCommand>> validInputs = new Dictionary<string, Func<ITerminalCommand>> { { "help", () => new TerminalCommandHelp() } };`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Sorry officer!! The way I worded my question, it was the right solution. This question has been re-worded to better explain my problem. Still new to C#, sorry for causing a catastrophe.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Dictionary<string, Type> validInputs = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
{
    { "help", typeof(TerminalCommandHelp) },
    { "exit", typeof(TerminalCommandExit) },
};

ITerminalCommand genericTerminalCommand = (ITerminalCommand)Activator.CreateInstance(validInputs["help"]);
```

Comment: How would one pass arguments into the constructor? I read that you can just append them after the Type argument, but CreateInstance() is overloaded to accept multiple different things and I don't want to conflict with those

Comment: You just pass them after the type, *in the order that they appear in your type's constructor*. If you only provide the `Type` and parameters, then you're using [`this overload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Object___) of `CreateInstance`.